# How to prove for sequence $(a_n) = \dfrac{3n^2 - 9n + 6}{n^3 + 5n^2 + 8n + 4}$ that is bounded between $0$ and $1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

just one question: How to prove for this sequence $$\left(a_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = \dfrac{3n^2 - 9n + 6}{n^3 + 5n^2 + 8n + 4}$$ that is bounded between $0$ and $1$. Can I use a mathematical induction here? (So, this means $0$ is lower bound, and $1$ is the upper bound.)

Is there any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, that from $a_k$ the sequence $a_n$ is decreasing? Find the smallest $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

$$
\left(a_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = \dfrac{3n^2 - 9n + 6}{n^3 + 5n^2 + 8n + 4} = \frac{3(n-2)(n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)^2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{array}\\
a_{n} 
&= \dfrac{3n^2 - 9n + 6}{n^3 + 5n^2 + 8n + 4}\\
&= 3\dfrac{n^2 - 3n + 2}{n^3 + 5n^2 + 8n + 4}\\
&< 3\dfrac{n^2}{n^3}
\qquad\text{for } n \ge 1\\
&=\dfrac{3}{n}\\
&\le 1
\qquad\text{for } n \ge 3\\
\text{and}\\
a(n)
&\gt 0
\qquad\text{for } n \ge 3\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Can you also use a derivative for that? @marty cohen

Comment: No for two reasons. First, the derivative of this expression is a mess. Second, a derivative can be unbounded while a function is bounded. For example, look at $\sin(x^3)/x$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\cfrac{3n^2-9n+6}{n^3+5n^2+8n+4}=0$, then $3n^2-9n+6=0$, or $3(n-2)(n-1)=0$, so since the denominator is always positive and the poynomial is positive for $x \notin (1,2)$, it is greater than zero for all integers.

If $\cfrac{3n^2-9n+6}{n^3+5n^2+8n+4}=1$, then $n^3+5n^2+8n+4=3n^2-9n+6$, or $n^3+2n^2+17n-2=0$, but you can see from any graphics calculator that that cubic is positive for all $n \geq 1$, and the denominator is more than $1$ for $n$ positive, so the function is less than one for all natural numbers

Comment: Ok, but how do I prove second part of exercise: Is there any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, that from $a_k$ the sequence $a_n$ is decreasing? Find the smallest $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Is that $a_{k + 1} \leq a_{k}$, so $\dfrac{3(k + 1)^2 - 9(k + 1) + 6}{(k + 1)^3 + 5(k+1)^2 + 8(k+1) + 4} \leq \dfrac{3k^2 - 9k + 6}{k^3 + 5k^2 + 8k + 4}$ and then solve for $k$?